# Solve $\int_{0}^{\delta*b} \sqrt{log(\frac{\delta}{x})}dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Could you help me to show that the integral 
$$\int_{0}^{\delta*b} \sqrt{log(\frac{\delta}{x})}dx
$$
with $\delta>0$ and $b>0$ is just a multiple of $\delta$, i.e. $\int_{0}^{\delta*b} \sqrt{log(\frac{\delta}{x})}dx=C_b\delta$ with $C_b \in \mathbb{R}$?

*$log$ is the natural logarithm

Comment: Try a rescaling of the variable.

Comment: What is $b?$ The RHS does not depend on $b,$ or is $C=C(b)?$

Comment: Yes, question edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Start changing variable $$\sqrt{\log \left(\frac{\delta}{x}\right)}\implies x=\delta e^{-t^2}\implies dx=-2 \delta e^{-t^2} t\,dt$$ So $$\int \sqrt{\log \left(\frac{\delta}{x}\right)}\,dx=-2 \delta\int e^{-t^2} t^2 \,dt$$ Now, one integration by parts to get a function which is familiar.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Could it be possible for you to write also the integration region of the transformed integral? Thank you

Comment: I let that part to you. It is very simple : what is $t$ when $x=0$ ? what is $t$ when $x=\delta\,b$ ?

Comment: Ok, I get lower bound $-\infty$ and upper bound $\sqrt{-\log(b)}$. Now integration by parts: $\int t^2e^{-t^2}dt=\int t t e^{-t^2}dt=-\frac{1}{2}\int t (-2t)e^{-t^2}dt=-\frac{1}{2}te^{-t^2}+\frac{1}{2}\int e^{-t^2}dt$. What is $\int e^{-t^2}dt$?

Comment: I have another doubt: writing $\int_{0}^{\delta*b} \sqrt{log(\frac{\delta}{x})}dx
$ implicitly means assuming $b<1$?